# How do I obtain the output of an oracle ddl statement in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have a script runner written in C# and I need to improve the logging to include the result of successful arbritary statements...

If the script fails I can log the details from the exception.
If it succeeds I'm having trouble obtaining the detail for my logs.

The input is an arbritary statement - usually ddl generated from Oracle Schema Compare and broken into individual commands by a custom tool.

I thought I could obtain the information by using dbms_output.get_line but that appears to only work when I actually log a line using dbms_output.put_line in a PLSQL block.

**What I'm trying to get:**
Statement:  "ALTER TABLE report_info MODIFY CONSTRAINT ri_fk ENABLE"
Result:  "Table altered"

I'm currently using the managed oracle data provider. This seems pretty straightforward but I'm having no luck finding the correct approach.

My Current approach (Psueudo-code) :

```
Create Connection
Call "begin dbms_output.enable; end;"
Run Query
While (line != null) Call "begin dbms_output.get_line(:line, :status); end;"
```

This works for dbms_output.put_line but does not return the result of arbritary queries.

Comment: I just discovered the connection.InfoMessage event which is helpful, It generates warnings but still doesn't provide the output of completely successful queries. So close.

Comment: Rather than looking for the "Result" message, could you have a corresponding confirmation or validation query to see if your CONSTRAINT is enabled to determine if your DDL statement has run successfully?

Comment: @MrMoose I do have a post process check that compares the database to source to ensure nothing was missed. Doing it at a per-command level wouldn't be practical as most of the statements are generated by an external tool.  Unfortunately this is more an issue of making sure I can provide the same level of logging that the DBAs are used to when we fully automate our deployments. While "Table Altered" may not provide any real information beyond a simple "Success" they are used to having that information and not providing it may prove to be a sticking point.

Comment: Hmmm, in SqlServer we'd use the [SqlConnection.InfoMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) to handle results normally printed in the "Messages" window of Management Studio. A quick search of InfoMessage for ODP returns some [promising results](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleInfoMessageEventHandlerDelegate.htm#i1010781)

Comment: Thanks.. I was messing around with that a bit. It definitely offers me more info than what I had but still doesn't return info level events like "Table Altered". I was hoping there was a way to alter the alert levels but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: The only other thing I can see of interest is the dbms_output package. There is an example of its use [here](http://oradim.blogspot.com.au/2007/05/odpnet-tip-retrieving-dbmsoutput-text.html) with regards to ODP.NET. 
I hope you manage to get the output you require.